# Views: Apply a wrapper to every 3 and 6 group of rows

Tags: theming, views

My Views Output is as follows

```
<div class="views-row-1">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-2">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-3">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-4">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-5">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-6">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-7">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-8">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-9">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-10">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-11">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-12">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-13">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-14">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-15">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-16">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-17">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-18">Content</div>
```

I would like to put a wrapper around every 3 and 6 group of Views rows.

So my mark up would look like this:

```
<div class="group group-1">
<div class="views-row-1">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-2">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-3">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="group group-2">
<div class="views-row-4">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-5">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-6">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-7">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-8">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-9">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="group group-3">
<div class="views-row-10">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-11">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-12">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="group group-4">
<div class="views-row-13">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-14">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-15">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-16">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-17">Content</div>
<div class="views-row-18">Content</div>
</div>
```

How can I do this? I know that I have to use `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` but I am not sure how to alter the `$row` variable to target every 3rd and 6th group.

Thanks in advance for any help that can be offered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few tips about the code:

- You also can make the logic in the preproccess or proccess hooks if you prefer
- To complete the information given by Jack: [Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) . This theory help us to build our strategy.

Aplication in a preprocces hook to separate the logic from the template:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars){

   $vars['prefix'] = array();
   $vars['suffix'] = array();
   $group = 1;
   $last_row = count($vars['rows']) -1;

   foreach($vars['rows'] as $id => &$row){

     $vars['prefix'][$id] = '';
     $vars['suffix'][$id] = '';

     // Apply modular arithmetic
     $remainder = $id % 9;

     // First div => 3 items
     if($remainder == 0){
       $vars['prefix'][$id] = "\n <div class=\"group group-$group\">";
     }

     if($remainder == 2){
       $vars['suffix'][$id] = '\n </div>';
       $group++;
     }

     // Second item => 6 items
     if($remainder == 3){
       $vars['prefix'][$id] = "\n <div class=\"group group-$group\">";
     }

     if($remainder == 8){
       $vars['suffix'][$id] = '\n </div>';     
       $group++;
     }

     // Close the div in case there are not enough items
     if($last_row == id && $remainder != 2 && $remainder != 8){
        $vars['suffix'][$id] = '\n </div>';
     }

   }

}
```

Your template in you theme that will overwrite the default template provided by views:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <?php if (!empty($prefix[$id])){ print $prefix[$id]; } ?>
    <div <?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print 'class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  <?php if (!empty($suffix[$id])){ print $suffix[$id]; } ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid having to create a template file for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php`

you can achieve a goal with the foreach loop:

```
<?php 
$group_nr = 1;                  // first group number
$last_row = count($rows) -1;    // last row
$wrapper  = 3;                  // put a wrapper around every 3 rows
?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
<?php if ($id % $wrapper == 0) {print '<div class="group group-'.$group_nr.'">'; $i = 0; $group_nr++; } ?>
    <div class="views-row-<?php print $id+1; ?>">
        <?php print $row; ?>
    </div>
<?php $i++; if ($i == $wrapper || $id == $last_row) print '</div>'; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

** In this example, every 3 rows will be wrapped in div with class "**group-[group nr]**"*

If these rows should be wrapped every sixth row as well, then you will need add some logic to tell whether do not wrapp in third row, but wait for the sixth.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks to Rufein I have noticed a lack of condition in case last row. It has been correted.

Comment: It's interesting to note that you can't have a consistent print function to output the views-row wrapper. It doesn't render if you try to print that.

Answer (score 1):

[Views Rows Wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rows_wrapper) module wraps every N rows with custom HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

`views-view-list.tpl.php` might be a better option to wrap groups of results.

This template is used to output the results list, and might be a bit more concise scope wise.

Answer (score 0):

Example in Twig for `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` wrapping every 3 rows:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a view of unformatted rows.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
 * - rows: A list of the view's row items.
 *   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
 *   - content: The row's content.
 * - view: The view object.
 * - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should be
 *   used on rows.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()
 */
#}
{% set wrapper_count = 3 %}
{% set wrapper_attributes = create_attribute({'class': ['group']}) %}
{% set row_classes = [default_row_class ? 'views-row'] %}

{% if title %}

  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>

{% endif %}

{% for row in rows %}
  {% if loop.index % wrapper_count == 1 %}
    <div {{ wrapper_attributes.addClass(['group-' ~ loop.index]) }}>
  {% endif %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{- row.content -}}
  </div>
  {% if loop.index % wrapper_count == 0 or loop.last %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```